# What is maximum width of a plank which is penetrated by bullet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

How to find max width of a plank which is penetrated by bullet taking into account the force of opposite reaction:

$$m = 0.09 kg$$ << should be 0.009
$$v_{bullet}=800\;m/s$$
$$F_{reaction}=-200*v$$

---

My attempt:

$$F_{reaction}=m*a$$
$$-200*\frac{dS}{dt}=m*\frac{d\frac{dS}{dt}}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{-200}{m}\int\frac{d\frac{dS}{dt}}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{-200}{2*m}*(\frac{dS}{dt})^2$$
$$\frac{dt}{dS}=\frac{-100}{m}$$
$$v^{-1}=-100/m$$
going further to get `S`:
$$S=\frac{m}{-100}\int1*dt$$
$$S=\frac{m*t}{-100}$$

What's next?

---

Trying to solve using formula:

$$m\, \frac{{\rm d} v}{{\rm d} x} = - \beta$$
$$dx=\frac{m*dv}{-\beta}$$
$$x=\frac{m}{-\beta}\int dv=\frac{m*v}{-\beta}=\frac{0.009*800}{-200}=-3.6E-2$$

---

The correct answer is $$3.6E-2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have a differential equation to solve:

$$m\,\frac{{\rm d} v}{{\rm d} t} =  m\,\frac{{\rm d} x}{{\rm d} t} \frac{{\rm d} v}{{\rm d} x} = m\,v\, \frac{{\rm d} v}{{\rm d} x}=-\beta \, v$$

where $\beta = 200$. Since we're interested in speed $v$ against distance $x$, we choose the form $v\,\mathrm{d}_x v$ for the acceleration. So we're left with:

$$m\, \frac{{\rm d} v}{{\rm d} x} = - \beta$$

which I believe will tell you what you need.

It looks as though you may still a bit shaky with underlying meanings of derivatives and integrals: are you taking a calculus course at the moment?

Comment: 1. Calculus was a while ago. 2. I'm not quite sure how to operate with notation you wrote. $$d_{x}\dot{v}=\frac{-\beta}{m}$$ Please explain at great details how to deal with it to get the answer.

Comment: Are my changes any clearer?

Comment: Thanks! Numeric part is OK. But why am I getting negative length?

Comment: You need to account for initial conditions. Solving the DE yields $v(x) = C - \beta x/m$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. But you know that when $x=0$, $v = v(0) = 800{\rm m\,s^{-1}}$. So $v(x) =  v(0)- \beta x/m$, and you seek $v(x) = 0$ (i.e. when the bullet comes to a halt). This should rid you of the negative sign